# Message frame with variable size

Tags: c++, network-programming

gcc compilers allows to declare some as:

```
struct Msg : public BaseMsg // BaseMsg could contain the message code and common stuff to all the diferent messages frames
{
  // some class state stuff whose layout must be contiguous 
  size_t len;     // length of variable data
  char buffer[0]; // here one could put data of variable size
};
```

In the past, I have used this style in order to manage messages frames. For example, I could do:

```
Msg * msg = (Msg*) malloc(sizeof(Msg) + additional_length);
memcpy(msg->buffer, /* some src addr for additional data */, additional_length);
```

In this way, I could put the constant message state and some additional data contiguous to the whole message, whose size often is variable, in a object of type `Msg`. Then I perform sending/receive once.

It is not a trivial technique, but in my modest experience is more concise, clear and efficient way than other alternatives (sending two separated messages and or to do more casting tricks).

Well, my interest is then to ask whether there are more efficient techniques or even if there is already a design pattern or library that simplifies the solution of such problems.

Thanks in advance for your attention

Answer (score 1):

If you are using [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) I cannot see why this would be inefficient

```
class Msg
{
public:
    Msg(size_t size, const char *const data)
    {
        m_data = new char[size + sizeof(size)];
        // Be careful with endiannes
        memcpy(m_data, &size, sizeof(size));
        memcpy(m_data + size, data, size);
    }

    const char *
    data() const
    {
        return m_data + sizeof(size_t);
    }

    size_t
    length() const
    {
        return *reinterpret_cast<size_t *>(m_data);
    }

    ~Msg()
    {
        delete[] m_data;
    }

private:
    char *m_data;
};
```

You could even add `send()` and `receive()` methods, if there is any good reason why this is bad I would love to know.

Comment: I think this approach might work for you. See the update.

Comment: Seems the `BaseMsg` is part of the packet. The author wants to construct the packet without calling methods like `get_bytes()`.